# Can I create Add-on or Plug-in for Android Mail Client?

Tags: android, email, plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin for Android Mail App. this plugin will filters my e-mails and show them differently like I need to made some special e-mail shows up in green color.

So, can I create such plugin ?  for the Android mail client or the Gmail for example ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure that the Android Mail App has a pluggable interface for you to add in your own code/widgets.

Your best bet is to create a new Mail App which will do what you want it to (you could even make it pluggable for others!!).  There exists the [Google-Api-Jar-Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), which I think you can use to access ones Gmail via HTTP requests.  But if your requirements are strictly to build a plug-in for the existing Android mail client, then I do not think that is possible currently.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the existing Gmail doesn't have the function you are looking for? You can create "Labels" and filter incoming email and mark them with the label. You can make the label color green and it will show the name of the label and the color in both Gmail and the Android Mail client.

Comment: ok , I know that I can create a filter for that but I need to do more thing that can't done by filter , as I need to change the mail view also , these things can't be configured as filters or anything else . so I need to create my own plug-in !